# How to use IndexMenu?

Tags: wiki, dokuwiki

I have installed the indexMenu plugin, in my sidebar I have created a menu like this:

```
...
{{indexmenu>.#1|js#kde.png}}
```

and I want to hide one entry in my menu:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a little bit confused, in case you want to hide this menu item, then why don't just not create this item?
Please correct me if my understanding wrong.

Maybe this link helps? http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:indexmenu#skip_files

Comment: this item is auto create, i use the  userhomepage plugin for create a personal home page by user and when i create this page i have this item in my menu

Comment: Find some information in plugin home page:"To get a better visualization you could use the hide_headpage option, that hides headpages in the rendered indexmenu tree."

Answer (score 0):

Go to the plugin-settings and type the following behind namespace ids to skip:
/(collaborateur)/